# Convert timestamp in milliseconds into a timezone in boost

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I have a client java library that parses ISO timestamp with timezone using joda-time library and returns a long value (milliseconds since epoch in UTC). I need to develop a server-side framework (in C++) that will use milliseconds since epoch and generate timestamp in any given timezone (e.g. "Europe/Zurich"). I can use local_date_time option like this :

```
posix_time ptime = epoch(date(1970,1,1)) + ms; //ms sent from client
tz_database tz;
tz.load_from_file(/*path to date_time_zonespec.csv*/);
time_zone_ptr ptr = tz.time_zone_from_region(regionStr); //regionStr = Europe/Zurich
local_date_time mytime(ptime, ptr);
```

However, I learnt from this post (  [C++: Will you choose boost::date_time or icu::date/time library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354806/c-will-you-choose-boostdate-time-or-icudate-time-library)) that boost::date_time time zone support is broken. A better option is boost::locale. Is there a way to the same steps as above using boost::locale? I was searching for examples online with boost::Locale but could not find any example similar to what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this [free, open-source C++11/14 timezone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) could help:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

date::zoned_time<std::chrono::milliseconds>
convert(date::sys_time<std::chrono::milliseconds> tp)
{
    return date::make_zoned(date::locate_zone("Europe/Zurich"), tp);
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << convert(date::floor<milliseconds>(system_clock::now())) << '\n';
    std::cout << convert(date::sys_time<milliseconds>{1469137715906ms}) << '\n';
}
```

This just output for me:

```
2016-07-21 23:48:35.906 CEST
2016-07-21 23:48:35.906 CEST
```

It is built on top of the C++11/14 `<chrono>` library.  `std::chrono::system_clock` measures time since 1970-01-01 UTC.  The timezone library helps translate that into localized timezones using the [IANA timezone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).

[Fully documented](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html), easy to use.  High performance.  Catches many errors at compile time.

[Examples and Recipes.](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I can't use C++ 11/14 since that will require porting existing code base.

Comment: @SantanuC:  Fair enough, and my sympathies about you being stuck on C++98/03. :-)